# What is the need for closing a file?

Tags: c, file

Why do we need to close a file that we opened? I know the problems like - it can't be accessed by another process if the current process doesn't close it. But why at the end of execution of a process the OS checks whether it is closed and closes it if opened. There must be a reason for that.

Comment: If you know the problems, you have your reasons: close a file to avoid that problems should be reason enough. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: it is not assured that the system will close files opened by the process (or free memory allocated by it) on exit: it might be just a common behaviour of popular systems, but it is not a rule.

Comment: @nvoigt he asks why it is necessary to close files **when the program exits**, because the operating system will do so anyway.

Comment: @nvoigt i just mean i know it can't be accessed by another process if the current process doesn't close it

Comment: @Philipp, no i didn't mean that i meant why do we need to close the file, even the Operating system checks if it is closed, there must be some good reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close a file the buffer is flushed and all you wrote on it it's persisted to the file. If you suddenly exit your program without flush (or close) your `FILE * stream`, you will probably lose your data.

Comment: Most operating systems closes files nicely when a process end. The only risk of losing data is if the process crashes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg isn't it the same with file handler? When the program exits, in most operating systems, all handlers are released, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it requires the process to exit. What if it's a long running process (like a server program)? If the process never closes the files it opens then it will run out of handles sooner or later.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it will run out of handlers and also memory I suppose, as, untile the buffers are not flushed they still use memory.

Answer (score 2):

Two words: Resource exhaustion. File handles, no matter platform, is a limited resource. If a process just opens file and never closes them, it will soon run out of file handles.

Comment: This leads me to a question that relates to this concept I'd like to ask (hope no one minds this in comment):
Suppose my program has created a lot of files, and the program crashes/abruptly terminates. On termination it'll close all the descriptors anyways for those files right? And if I want that those files should get deleted as well in such scenario, any way to achieve that?

Comment: @DiwakarSharma If your process crashes, the actual file descriptors will be closed, but any buffers may not be properly flushed (so you may loose data). And the only way to delete those files (if they are temporary) is to either use proper temporary files (as opened by e.g. [`tmpfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile)) or remove them manually.

Answer (score 1):

A file can certainly be accessed by another process while it is opened by one.  Some semantics depend on the operating system.  For example, in Unix, two or more processes may open a file concurrently to write.  Almost all systems will allow readonly access to multiple processes.

You open a file to connect the byte stream into the process.  You close the file to disconnect the two.  When you write into the file, the file may not get modified right away due to buffering.  That implies that the memory buffer of the file is modified but the change is not immediately reflected into the file on disk.  The OS will reflect the changes in disk when it has enough data for performance reason.  When you close the file, the OS will *flush out* the changes into the file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you "get" a resource, it is good practice to release it when you have done.

I think it's not a good thing to trust what an O.S. would do when the process end: it might free resources or not. Common O.S. does it: they close files, free allocated memory, …

But if it's not part of the standard of the language you use (e.g. if it implements garbage collectors), then you shouldn't rely on that common behaviour.

Otherwise, the risk is that your application would lock/eat resources on some systems, even if it ended.

Answer (score 1):

In this way it is just a good practise. You  are not obliged to close files at the end.

Imagine you'll write a genial but messy method. You'll forget about the caveats and later find out, that this method may be used somewhere else. Then you'll try to use this method maybe in a loop and you'll find out that your programm is unexpectedly crashing. You'll have to go deeper in the code and fix that. So why won't you make the function clean at the beginning?

Do you have something against (or are you afraid of) closing files?

Comment: The point is i am having a viva tomorrow, if the teacher asks this question -- what is the need for closing file, i can't ask her back are you afraid of closing the file..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/

When writing into an output file, the information is hold in a buffer and closing the file is a way to be sure that everything is posted to the file.